# Javascript: is biding events using Jquery's bind() better than simply doing the onclick='bla()' and why?

Tags: javascript

Is binding events using JQuery's bind() considered better than simply doing the onclick='bla(this)' and why ?

Thanks !

Comment: Keeping JavaScript code out of markup is really a good idea.

Comment: What if the javascript is necessary for the page to make sense? Would you then inline the necessary parts in a script-tag and call the "optional" library from the onclick-hooked inline script?

Comment: HTML is about **content**, not behavior.  If behaviors of some HTML elements should be evident to reflect meaning, then they should have classes like "animated" or "informational" or whatever.  (That said, I'm not a formalist or fanatic or anything; I'm intensely pragmatic in fact :-)

Comment: Oh, and I prefer to "bind" behaviors to HTML implicitly, and since it's good to have JavaScript be cacheable I strongly like to keep as much as possible in separate JavaScript static resources.

Comment: Pointy, and apparently poetic too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because [Unobtrusive JavaScript (UJS)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) is the new normal.

For me, the separation of markup from behavior is the biggest benefit, although there are other things that are handy about it, and everyone likes different aspects.

@Esailija correctly points out that jQuery makes UJS *much* easier, in terms of level of work, browser compatibility, browser workarounds, and so on. UJS doesn't *depend* on jQuery, but JS libraries have made it viable across a wider swath of functionality.

Comment: Meh, I was about to write an answer of benefits of the jQuery event model (normalization, bug fixes, delegation, shimmed events such as mouseenter and mouseleave etc etc) over bare bones html events then saw this get checkmarked. fuu

Comment: @Esailija No reason not to add it, although it's not intrinsically related--jQuery makes UJS hugely easier, though. I'll add a note to the answer for ya' ;)

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery events you get 6 years worth of bug fixes, normalization of the event object, namespaces, support for events such as mouseenter, mouseleave, focusin and focusout which are originally proprietary IE events and event delegation.

With events attached with any sort of js (not just jQuery) you gain:

- Useful object context
- Useful function scope
- Ability to attach multiple handlers for the same event on the same element

And in case you are generating html dynamically:

- Sanity as you don't have to concatenate strings to generate code, you just write the event handler code just like any other code without having to worry about how your strings end up by first being interpreted as a javascript string, then by html, and then as javascript code (yes, three phases. I didn't even get the following right on the first revision):

  ```
  var html = '<div onclick="alert(\''+someVar+'\'+\'hello\');"></div>'
  ```

  is not exactly easy to write. Compare to

  ```
      $("<div>", {
          click: function () {
              alert(someVar + "hello");
          }
      });
  ```

Answer (score 0):

In my experience there is a price to pay for abstractions which should be weighted against the benefits of using them.

In the case of jQuery I have found that the time it saves me far outweighs any of the disadvantages. To give you an example, how would you code the following example in standard javascript.

```
$("ul").on("click", "li", function(){ });
```

This jQuery [method](http://api.jquery.com/on/) attaches an event handler to all present and future li elements.

Implementing this functionality is not a trivial task and by using jQuery you are using a high quality code base that attempts to abstract browser differences and helps you focus on programming.